# What do the variable debug color mean in the Eclipse Java Debugger?

Tags: java, debugging

[Image of Java Debugger Variables Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y66LH.png)

What do the green and red colors indicate in the variables section of the java debugger? Is there a website that lists all the different symbols? I know that the gray L indicates that it is a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse documentation has a full [list of icons](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm).

Red square is private method. The green circle means it's a public method, though also apparently used for `this`.